# pb with callback in the python optparse module

Tags: python, callback, optparse

I'm playing with Python 2.6 and its optparse module. I would like to convert one of my arguments to a datetime through a callback but it fails.

Here is the code:

```
def parsedate(option, opt_str, value, parser):
    option.date = datetime.strptime(value, "%Y/%m/%d")

def parse_options(args):
    parser = OptionParser(usage="%prog -l LOGFOLDER [-e]", version="%prog 1.0")
    parser.add_option("-d", "--date", action="callback", callback="parsedate", dest="date")  
    global options
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args(args)
    print options.date.strftime()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        parse_options(sys.argv[1:])
```

I get an error  `File: optparse.py in _check_callback "callback not callable"`. I guess I'm doing something wrong in the way I define my callback but what ? and why ? Can anyone help ?

**UPDATE**: As I said in my comment, I think the best way to have a datetime in the options of a command line script is by extending optparse as suggested in the [python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse-extending-optparse)

the following class really works fine for that:

```
from copy import copy
from optparse import Option, OptionValueError
from datetime import datetime

def check_date(option, opt, value):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(value, "%Y/%m/%d")
    except ValueError:
        raise OptionValueError(
            "option %s: invalid date value: %r. Should have a format like \"YYYY/MM/DD\"" % (opt, value))

class dateOption (Option):
    TYPES = Option.TYPES + ("date",)
    TYPE_CHECKER = copy(Option.TYPE_CHECKER)
    TYPE_CHECKER["date"] = check_date
```

Anyway, many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have parsedate in quotes.  It should not be.

Comment: anyway thanks a lot... But actually I'm wondering if I have the good strategy here. I'm wondering if I wouldn't have to extend Option